# Where can HttpContext.User be set?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sqlmembershipprovider, custom-membershipprovider

Environment: MVC3 SqlMemberShipProvider

I added an empty

```
public void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {}
```

in the MvcApplication class in Global.asax.cs and put a breakpoint there.  It was fired on every page access.  The sender is of type MvcApplication, which has a **User** property and a **Context** property.

If I am not logged in, **User** and **Context**.User are null.

If I am logged in, **User** and **Context**.User are set to a GenericPrincipal containing my logged in name.

So it seems that SqlMemberShipProvider (if not who) is setting the User object.  May I know how/where this is done?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess you are using Membership together with FormsAuthentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using Membership together with FormsAuthentication?
Maybe together with login control?
If you are using FormsAuthentication then it is `FormsAuthenticationModule` that reads the identity cookie from the browser and then constructs the `IPrincipal` object from that cookie.

Comment: Yes to all your questions.

The real question I wanted to ask was how does FormsAuthenticationModule access the MvcApplication object in order to set the IPrincipal.

Comment: Using dotPeek (http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) look for OnAuthenticate in FormsAuthenticationModule.

What it does is basically HttpContext.Current.Principal = new Principal(...)

Comment: Sorry, should be HttpContext.User = new Principal(...) 
I haven't tried, but maybe you could assign your own value to HttpContext.Current.User in Application_AuthenticateRequest otherwize you may write your own module to handle authenticaiton

Comment: Found it!  The HttpApplication object is passed to FormsAuthenticationMoudle.Init and also FormsAuthenticationEventArgs for various events contains the User object.